# Validation Drop-down list in Excel Table via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to save some data entered on one worksheet to the Sales table I have on another worksheet.

The code below works fine except for one minor issue related to the Data Validation drop-down.

When I enter the data on my main worksheet and run this code from the same main worksheet or any other worksheet in my workbook, the data is saved to my Sales table, but the drop-down is not inserted into the column "P".

If I run this code from the worksheet, which has the Sales table, everything worked as intended.

Here is my code:

```
    Public Function updateSalesInfo(wbk As Workbook, strFileName As String)

    Dim lngRow          As Long
    Dim wks             As Worksheet
    Dim tableListObject As ListObject
    Dim tableObjectRow  As ListRow
    
    Set wks = wbk.Sheets("Sales")
    Set tableListObject = wks.ListObjects("Sales")
    Set tableObjectRow = tableListObject.ListRows.Add
          
    With wks
    
        lngRow = .Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
        
        With .Range("B" & lngRow)
            .Value = Range("_newInvoice").Value
            .Offset(, 1).Value = Format(Now(), "mmmm d, yyyy")
            .Offset(, 2).Value = Range("rngCustID").Value
            .Offset(, 3).Value = Range("rngCustName").Value
            .Offset(, 9).Value = Range("_invoiceDueDate").Value
            .Offset(, 11).Value = "=IF(ISBLANK(B" & lngRow & "),"""",L" & lngRow & "-J" & lngRow & ")"
            .Offset(, 12).Value = "=IF(AND(K" & lngRow & "<=TODAY(),M" & lngRow & "<0),""Yes by ""&(TODAY()-K" & lngRow & ")&"" Days"","""")"
            .Offset(, 13).Value = Range("rngLoginUserName").Value
            .Offset(, 14).Value = "Draft"
        End With
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("B" & lngRow), Address:=strFileName, ScreenTip:="Click to open a file"
     
        With wks.Range("P" & lngRow).Validation
             .Delete
             .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="=Settings!" & Range("rngInvoiceStatus").Address
             .IgnoreBlank = True
             .InCellDropdown = True
             .InputTitle = ""
             .ErrorTitle = ""
             .InputMessage = ""
             .ErrorMessage = ""
             .ShowInput = True
             .ShowError = True
    
   
        End With
    End With
   
    Set wks = Nothing
    
End Function
```

Any suggestions about how to do it the right way?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem that was causing the issue I have had with this code.

In the validation, `Formula1` should only include the range and not the address to which the range refers.

So instead of having this: `Formula1:="=Settings!" & Range("rngInvoiceStatus").Address`

I now have this: `Formula1:="=rngInvoiceStatus"` and all works as intended.